# Conditional input fields for Google sheets? (to assist data quality)

Tags: validation, user-interface, google-sheets, user-input, user-experience

Im struggling with my users putting data into google sheets incorrect. **I need to know if there is anyway to set conditions to how users input data in google sheets?** ie a watermark in the cells guiding them on how to enter data eg.`YYYY-MM-DD`

[image: VIEW EXAMPLE]

Any other ideas on how to guide users to input data correctly into google sheet are also welcome.

Comment: Did you try Google Forms? They can store content in a Google Sheet and offer a very guided experience to the final user

Comment: No I havent even considered it, will definitely try it! Thank you for you insight.

Answer (score 2):

there is no such thing as watermark but there are ways...

add column before date column and use this formula and drag down:

```
=IFERROR({"", "yyyy-mm-dd"})
```

[image]

then use conditional formatting:

[image]

then hide column:

[image]

then use data validation:

[image: 0]

then use internal pre-formatting:

[image: 0]

---

final result:

[image: 0]

Comment: You are such a G